# Spritebatch drawing the other way

Tags: c#, rotation, monogame, spritebatch

I am drawing a rectangle using a emptytexture (1x1) and I use the following:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(EmptyTexture, new Rectangle((int)MyPosition.X + MyTexture.Width / 2, (int)MyPosition.Y + MyTexture.Height / 2, 100, 2000), null, Color.Red, MyDirection + MathHelper.ToRadians(180), new Vector2(0, 0), SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
```

which does this:
[image]
[image]

But now I am trying to make another rectangle next to that one which looks like this:
[image]

But when you rotate the ship it rotates like this:
[image]

I've done this by the following:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(EmptyTexture, new Rectangle((int)(MyPosition.X + MyTexture.Width / 2) + 100, (int)MyPosition.Y + MyTexture.Height / 2, 100, 2000), null, Color.DarkRed, MyDirection + MathHelper.ToRadians(180), new Vector2(0, 0), SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
```

But what I am trying to do is to make the point of rotation of the 2nd one at the middle of the ship like the other one but it's drawn the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

```
spriteBatch.Draw(EmptyTexture, new Rectangle((int)(MyPosition.X + MyTexture.Width / 2) + 100, (int)MyPosition.Y + MyTexture.Height / 2, 100, 2000), null, Color.DarkRed, MyDirection + MathHelper.ToRadians(180), **new Vector2(0, 0)**, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
```

I had to change the origin

new Vector2(0, 0) to new Vector2(1, 0)

I have no clue why though

Comment: The new vector moves the pivot point the sprite rotates around to the opposite corner.